# Java sort one always on top

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following class:

```
    public class Rating{
      private int userId;
      private int value;

   //getters and setters
    }
```

I want every time userId == 1000 to be on top and below to be all rating in descending order.

I tried the following but does not seem to work:

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            if(o2.getUserId() == 1000){
                return 1;
            }
            return Integer.compare(o2.getValue(), o1.getValue());
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: What if `o1.getUserId() == 1000)`?

Comment: `returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.`, beside that you ignore `o1` you just check if `o2` has the `id == 1000` and order `o1` as greater than `o2` this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1.getUserId() == o2.getUserId()) {
            return Integer.compare(o2.getValue(), o1.getValue());
        } else if(o1.getUserId() == 1000) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o2.getUserId() == 1000) {
            return 1;
        }
        return Integer.compare(o2.getValue(), o1.getValue());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this process :

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
      if (o1.getUserId() < 1000) {
          return -1;
      } 
      else if(o1.getUserId() == 1000) {
          return 0;
      } 
      else if (o1.getUserId() > 1000) {
          return 1;
      }
      else if (o2.getUserId() < 1000) {
        return -1;
      } 
      else if(o2.getUserId() == 1000) {
            return 0;
      } 
      else if (o2.getUserId() > 1000) {
            return 1;
      }
      return Integer.compare(o2.getValue(), o1.getValue());
  });
```